# How do I bind a command to an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to create a few modified weapons/items in Minecraft, so that when you hit something (left click) with the specific item, it executes a command. I have already found a few answers that make it so that if you use a specific item it executes a command, but that applies for every single one of that item; for example, if a blaze rod gives you strength, every blaze rod in the game will give you strength. Is there a way to do this with only one item?

Comment: This can be achieved using plugins. Is this possible for you?

Comment: It depends on how you are getting the item. If it is trough commands, yes, you can mark that specific item with a tag. If you aren't using /give, then you are able to rename the item in an anvil, but that means anyone renaming the item would be able to use the special one. There might be a way to transform a random blaze rod into a special one by a certain %, if that works for you.

Comment: @BunnyMerz This would work... but I am not sure how to do it, exactly.

Comment: @MrParrot Unfortunately, I am on a server and only certain plugins can be imported, so it really matters which one.

Comment: "This would work" Which of the 3 solutions do you want? Tagged item, Named item or random drop?

Comment: Never mind, I discovered how to do it. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

Give yourself a blaze rod that has a very special tag and then iterate through the players to see if they are holding the the speical blaze rod.

say
`give @s blaze_rod{Unbreakable:3b} 1`
gives you a blaze rod with unbreakable 3b tag.

run this in a tick function now
`execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:3b}}}] run effect give @s strength 2 255 true`

This would give effect strength level 255 to anyone who is holding the rod.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can actually use custom nbt tags, instead of applying impossible values on existing tags. For example, `give @s blaze_rod{mytag:1b} 1` can be tested with `execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Count:1,tag:{mytag:1b}}}]`